# Self-Referential Definition Not Working in Haskell

Tags: haskell

New to Haskell, but I've run into something that's confusing to me, and I can't explain it or find any documentation.

If I have the following code:

```
-- Simple 2D Coordinate Data Structure
data Point = Point
   { x :: !Float
   , y :: !Float }
   deriving (Show)

-- Constant origin (always at (0,0) unless otherwise specified)
origin = Point 0 0

-- Return a Point that has been shifted by the specified amounts
move :: Point -> Float -> Float -> Point
move p dx dy = Point { x=xs+dx, y=ys+dy }
    where
        xs = x p
        ys = y p
```

Now, this code works perfectly well

```
*Main> origin
Point {x = 0.0, y = 0.0}
*Main> move origin 1 3
Point {x = 1.0, y = 3.0}
*main> otherpoint = move origin 4 4
*main> origin
Point {x = 0.0, y = 0.0}
*main> otherpoint
Point {x = 4.0, y = 4.0}
*main> :t otherpoint
otherpoint :: Point
```

The issue comes if I attempt to move a point and assign it to itself

```
*main> otherpoint = move otherpoint 5 5
*main> otherpoint
^CInterrupted --Freezes
*main> otherpoint = move otherpoint 6 6
^CInterrupted --Freezes
```

Comment: I'm sure there are many good duplicate to point this question to, but I can't find any of them. Anyone else have an idea?

Comment: Haskell does not have variables, only constants!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`=` doesn't perform assignment; it *equates* two things. You are creating a recursive definition by saying that `otherpoint` and `move otherpoint 5 5` are the same thing and are interchangeable. That means when you try to evaluate the call to `move`, it tries to evaluate `otherpoint`, which leads to the next call to `move`, etc.

You can't simply "rebind" a variable in Haskell. Instead, use a different name.

```
nextpoint = move otherpoint 5 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Let’s look at an example of a self-referential definition that does work:

```
Prelude> let a = 1:a
Prelude> take 10 a
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

As chepner mentioned, an equals sign in Haskell is is not an assignment, but a definition.  It has very different semantics than an equals sign in, for example, C or Java.  In general, each variable in Haskell can only be given one definition, not changed.  So the example above works because it defines `a` as the list whose head is `1` and whose tail is `a`.  When `take 10 a` tries to find the second element of `a`, that’s the head of the tail of `a`.  The tail of `a` is `a`, so the head of the tail of `a` is `1`.  Because Haskell lazily evaluates only the elements of `a` that it needs, it computes a finite number of recursions and then stops, but if you tried to compute `length a`, it would go into an infinite loop.

What you wrote is the equivalent of `a = a + 1`.  That is, the definition of `point` at the bottom of your post is well-typed, but infinitely recursive.  The recursive computation never reduces to anything simpler; it is not well-founded.